# Splitting a sentence into smaller phrases with a command and 2 optional parameters

Tags: python, regex

- First split the sentence into smaller phrases with words from the command list
- The words can be anywhere in the sentence
- After the word there can be another word and a number ( both optional)
- Remove any words not in any of lists.

Small example:

```
txt = "dash dash forward dash backward 5 5 walk walk forward walk forward 5 a"
commands = ['dash', 'walk']
directions = ['forward', 'backward']
```

Should split a sentence into smaller phrases:

```
dash
dash forward
dash backward 5
--> cut out 5
walk
walk forward
walk forward 5
--> cut out a
```

Comment: You are quite familiar with SO yourself; you should know better than giving us just a problem description.

Comment: Let me give it a bit more information.

Comment: That's not it. Where are [your own attempts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) on solving this problem?

Comment: I should say more like not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly solution, but it works:

```
txt = "dash dash forward dash backward 5 5 walk walk forward walk forward 5 a"
commands =['dash','walk']
directions= ['forward','backward']
words = txt.split(" ")
i = 0
res = []
while i < len(words):
    if words[i] not in commands:
        print(f"cuts off {words[i]}")
        i += 1
        continue
    tmp = [words[i]]
    if i + 1 < len(words) and words[i+1] in directions:
        tmp.append(words[i+1])
        if i + 2 < len(words) and words[i+2] not in commands:
            tmp.append(words[i+2])
    i = i + len(tmp)
    res.append(" ".join(tmp))
print(res)
```

Output

```
cuts off 5
cuts off a
['dash', 'dash forward', 'dash backward 5', 'walk', 'walk forward', 'walk forward 5']
```

Comment: I'll check it out when I got time but if it works I'll accept it.

Comment: Re *"An ugly solution"*: Yes, it doesn't look very [Pythonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic#Adjective), more like a [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) program.